# How to get the total pages of epub.js? book.locations.total return incorrect info

Tags: javascript, react-native, epub, epub.js

I have a problem while working with epub.js and react native. The return of book.locations is not corresponding to the number of pages its rendered on screen.

Example in mobile view, I can see that there is total 7 pages. However, in book.locations it will depend on the number of chars input (ex: book.locations.generate(500) it will render 11 locations, book.locations.generate(1000) it will render 4 location).
How can I get the exactly number of page and its cfi which displayed on screen? Thank you so much.